# is there a more efficient alternative for this SQL query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Im working on a movie data set that has tables for movies, genre and a bridge table in_genre.
The following query tries to find common genres between two movies. Im doing two joins to get the genre list and a intersect to find common genres.
Is there a more efficient way?

Table schema:

- movie : movie_id(PK)(int)
- in_genre(bridge_table): movie_id(FK)(int), genre_id(int)

```
SELECT count(*) as common_genre 
FROM(
    // getting genres of first movie
    SELECT in_genre.genre_id
    FROM movie INNER JOIN in_genre ON movie.id = in_genre.movie_id
    WHERE movie.id = 0109830

    INTERSECT

    // getting genres of second movie
    SELECT in_genre.genre_id
    FROM movie INNER JOIN in_genre ON movie.id = in_genre.movie_id
    WHERE movie.id = 1375666
) as genres
```

Comment: Twice `EXISTS()` ?

Comment: exists works thanks for suggestion@wildplasser, @lLukStorms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it only needs the data from `in_genre` then there's no need to join the `movie` table.

And you can use an `EXISTS` to find the common genres.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT genre_id) as common_genre
FROM in_genre ig
WHERE movie_id = 0109830
  AND EXISTS 
  (
      SELECT 1
      FROM in_genre ig2
      WHERE ig2.movie_id = 1375666
        AND ig2.genre_id = ig.genre_id
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the genres, I would simply do:

```
SELECT genre_id as common_genre
FROM in_genre ig
WHERE movie_id IN (0109830, 1375666)
GROUP BY genre_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

If you want the count, a subquery is simple enough:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT genre_id as common_genre
      FROM in_genre ig
      WHERE movie_id IN (0109830, 1375666)
      GROUP BY genre_id
      HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
     ) g;
```

If you want full information about the genres, then I would suggest `exists`:

```
select g.*
from genres g
where exists (select 1
              from in_genre ig
              where ig.genre_id = g.genre_id and ig.movie_id = 0109830
             ) and
      exists (select 1
              from in_genre ig
              where ig.genre_id = g.genre_id and ig.movie_id = 1375666
             );
```